# QueryForList not setting parameters

Tags: java, security, prepared-statement, in-clause

I have the a piece of code resembling the following. I'm trying to parameterize the given query and put a list after the IN clause.

```
public List<Map<String,Object>> parameterize(List<String> list) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    String b = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE abc IN (:value)";
    MapSqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    namedParameters.addValue("value", list));
    List<Map<String,Object>> results = getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(b, namedParameters);
    if (results == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No values.");
    return results;
 }
```

But this isn't working and I'm getting the following exception

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: JZ0SE: Invalid object type (or null object) specified for setObject().
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseError(ErrorMessage.java:775)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybPreparedStatement.setObject(SybPreparedStatement.java:1356)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setObject(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:721)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:401)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:234)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:165)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.doSetValue(ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.java:65)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.setValues(ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.java:46)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:644)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:589)
    ... 53 more
```

I have tried using PreparedStatement instead too but that doesn't work either. Please help!

Comment: Are you sure that list argument is not null?

Comment: Yup. It works when I just directly append the list values as a string to the query.

Comment: Are you using NamedParametedJdbcTemplate, because from the stacktrace it looks like you use standard JdbcTemplate? From [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) This class delegates to a wrapped JdbcTemplate once the substitution from named parameters to JDBC style '?' placeholders is done at execution time. It also **allows for expanding a List of values to the appropriate number of placeholders**.

Comment: Nopes. I used the standard Jdbc template. Thanks! I'll try with that.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helps. Moved comment that worked to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NamedParametedJdbcTemplate, because from [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html):

This class delegates to a wrapped JdbcTemplate once the substitution from named parameters to JDBC style '?' placeholders is done at execution time. **It also allows for expanding a List of values to the appropriate number of placeholders.**